# How does GNU make's "file" function work?

Tags: gnu-make, gnu

I am thinking I may need to use the file function in GNU make, and just can not follow the example they give. I have looked online, but don't see any post with more explanation. Here is the example they give:

```
program: $(OBJECTS)
$(file >$@.in,$^)
$(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
@rm $@.in
```

I think I know what it is doing at a high level as it is explained in the manual.

```
$@.in
```

is a list of all the target files

```
$^
```

is a list of the source files

I am not sure how `@$@.in` is used on the third line or what there is an `@` sign at the beginning. What does that mean please? What does it supposed to do?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `$(file)`? Also do you have a new enough version of make for that? That's new to 4.1 I think.

Comment: This is a good question. The manual talked about using this function to pass parameters to the command line? I kind of figured if no one has used it so far, perhaps I can get by w/o it.

Comment: I know I had 4.0 with Ubuntu 14.10. I downgraded it for compatibility with Android Studio. I am not sure what they are pushing now with the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: Just for clarity; I downgraded make for compatibility with AOSP.

Comment: Yeah, looks like `$(file)` is a 4.0 feature not 4.1.

Comment: You can use it instead of shelling out to `cat`/etc. or to work around line-length limits (if you have them but you likely don't in most cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the operation of that recipe is given in the prose immediately preceding it in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Function):

> Many commands use the convention that an argument prefixed with an @ specifies a file containing more arguments. Then you might write your recipe in this way:
>
> ```
> program: $(OBJECTS)
>     $(file >$@.in,$^)
>     $(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
>     @rm $@.in
> ```

- `$@` is the target file (there is only one of those in any given recipe)
- `$@.in` is the target file with `.in` added to the end of the name.
- `$^` is the "list" of the all the prerequisites of the target.
- `@$@.in` is the name of the target with `.in` at the end and `@` at the start.

So the `$(file ...)` call in that recipe writes the list of prerequisites of the target into a file called `program.in` in "overwrite" mode and then passes that file name to the `$(CMD)` command using the `@filename` convention that was mentioned.